# ¿Cómo obtener clave key de un array con array_search?

Tags: php, array

Estoy buscando si el nombre 'josue' existe en mi array, para lo cual estoy usando el array_search, pero también quiero obtener la clave 'aaa' que lo contiene.

este es un ejemplo de lo que tengo

```
<?php
    $array=array('aaa'=>array("nombre"=>"josue"),'bbb'=>array("nombre"=>"victor"));
    echo array_search("josue", array_column($array, 'nombre'));
?>
```

el resultado que obtengo es 0, pero lo que yo quiero es obtener el 'aaa'

este es otro ejemplo con un array normal,

```
<?php
    $a=array("aaa"=>"red","bbb"=>"green","ccc"=>"blue");
    echo array_search("red",$a);
?>
```

este si me devuelve el 'aaa' ,

como hago para que pueda obtener el resultado que quiero con el primer array.

Comment: Puedes intentar esto.
$array=array('aaa'=>array("nombre"=>"josue"),'bbb'=>array("nombre"=>"victor"));
        foreach ($array as $i => $item)
        {
            $buscar = array_search('josue', $item);
            if($buscar !== false)
            {
                echo $i;
            }
        }

Comment: Al hacer `array_column` se pierde el índice asociativo y se transforma en un índice numérico.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar un bucle para comprobar si el valor existe en el array:

```
<?php
    $array=array('aaa'=>array("nombre"=>"josue"),'bbb'=>array("nombre"=>"victor"));
    echo searchForValue("josue", $array);

    function searchForValue($value, $array) {
        foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
            $nameExists = array_search($value, $val);
            if ($nameExists !== false) {
                return $key;
            }
        }
        return 'El nombre ' . $value . ' no existe en el array';
    }
```